# R - transform a list of variable vectors to data.frame with additional column by nested lapply

Tags: r, nested-loops, apply, lapply

Have a `list` of `character()` vectors of different length. How you can transform it into a `data.frame` efficiently (with some `Xapply` function). Also a additional ID column is required.

INPUT

```
# sentences are like:
sent1 <- "ab"
sent2 <- "bc"
sent3 <- "cd"
sent4 <- "de"

# sections
sec1 <- c(sent1, sent3)
sec2 <- c(sent4, sent3, sent2)
sec3 <- c(sent3)
sec4 <- c(sent2, sent1)

# the whole list
text <- list(sec1, sec2, sec3, sec4)
```

my try is NOT WORKING

```
text2.df <- lapply(text, function(i)
                         lapply(text[[i]], function(j) 
                                           data.frame(ID=paste(sprintf("%02d", i), sprintf("%03d", j), sep = ""), # creates the requred sentence IDs (works properly)
                                                               Sentence=text[[i]][j])))
```

Requred OUTPUT

```
> text2.df 
     ID Sentences
1 01001        ab
2 01002        cd
3 02001        de
4 02002        cd
5 02003        bc
6 03001        cd
7 04001        bc
8 04002        ab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a lot of difference with your previous question except the last rbind. You should carefully read the answers.

```
ll <- lapply(seq_along(text),function(i)
  data.frame(ID = paste(sprintf("%02d", i), 
                   sprintf("%03d", seq_along(text[[i]])), 
                   sep = ""),
             sent=text[[i]]))

do.call(rbind,ll) 
     ID sent
1 01001   ab
2 01002   cd
3 02001   de
4 02002   cd
5 02003   bc
6 03001   cd
7 04001   bc
8 04002   ab
```

Comment: Nice! Thank You! The solutions may seem pretty similar but I didn't got it. Actually even now I don't quite understand how `do.call` works. Have to learn more. Maybe I'm also a bit tired. Sorry, and thank you much, I tried 1,5 days before asking the first question..

Comment: @alex you are welcome. My remark is just you have to simplify your question as possible to avoid confusion. Creating list( previous question)  and transforming it to a data.frame are different questions.

Comment: Thank You for your understanding. This issue is not stopping. Can you interpret this error/suggest a solution?
`> text.list <- lapply(seq_along(text), function(i)
+                              data.frame(ID=paste(sprintf("%02d", i), sprintf("%03d", seq_along(text[[i]])), sep = ""),
+                                         Sentence=text[[i]][j]))
Error in text[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Called from: paste(sprintf("%02d", i), sprintf("%03d", seq_along(text[[i]])), 
    sep = "")`

Comment: Your  list is no longer  called text, (maybe you rename it). Type `text` in the console to check this. R use the built in function `text`(closure type).

Comment: Thank you much for your help. Have a nice day and a Happy New Year!